# Filter data frame to keep rows until column values changes to 0

Tags: r, dplyr, dt, date-arithmetic

I have this data frame,

```
`df <- tibble(
  key = rep(1:3, c(8,4,5)),
  Date = c(seq(as.Date('2016-12-17'), as.Date('2016-12-19'), '1 day'),
       seq(as.Date('2016-12-21'), as.Date('2016-12-23'), '1 day'),
       seq(as.Date('2016-12-29'), as.Date('2016-12-30'), '1 day'),
       seq(as.Date('2017-05-18'), as.Date('2017-05-21'), '1 day'),
       seq(as.Date('2017-05-18'), as.Date('2017-05-20'), '1 day'),
       seq(as.Date('2017-05-23'), as.Date('2017-05-24'), '1 day')),
  flag= c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
  )`
```

For each 'Key', I need the max value of 'Date' before 'Flag' turns 0 for the first time or if there are no 0 flag for a 'Key', then return max value of 'Date'.

I need the following output.

```
key Date        flag
 1 2016-12-19     1
 2 2017-05-21     1
 3 2017-05-20     1
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code below I am using the fact that match returns the position of the first match. I then create an extra column with the index of the rows so that I can filter all the rows after the first occurence of `flag = 1`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(idx = 1:n()) %>% 
  filter(idx < match(0,flag) | is.na(match(0,flag))) %>% 
  summarise(Date = max(Date))
```

Hope this helps!!